# How to exclude name of ordered test from test results on tfs build?

Tags: tfsbuild, ordered-test, test-results

I have a few ordered tests with some UI tests. Then I have one ordered test which contains other ordered tests:

[image]

This ordered test (which contains many others ordered tests) is running every night within TFS Build. If some UI tests faile, then names of ordered tests in which are failed tests are displayed in test results from TFS Build:

[image]

Is it possible with any settings to exclude the name of the ordered tests from test results? I would like to see in the test results just names of the failed tests.

Answer (score 0):

I believe when creating a build definition in TFS build you can specify if tests should be run on the *process* tab of the build definition.

Part of the parameters for the tests is the *Test sources spec* value which (in my TFS anyway) defaults to `**\*test*.dll;**\*test*.appx`

Perhaps if you put the tests you don't want to run in a different assembly that doesn't match the filter you can get what you want.

Alternatively there is also a parameter with the name *Test case filter*, but I'm not familiar with what you can put in there to filter tests, but the name sounds promising.

Comment: Hi Robba, thanks for the reply. I know that it is possible to specify Test Filter Criteria. But this option is not suitable for my case. I run the tests by calling the *.orderedtest which contains many others orderedtests (playlists). I want to run all of tests from all of orderedtest (playlists). But if some UI test failed, I would like to see in the test results just name of the failed test and not the name of orderedtest (playlist) in which is this failed test included.

Comment: Ah, too bad. I hope you find the answer to your question